# How to create a method for different combinations in Java?

Tags: java, methods, combinations

I am working on a currency converter. I need to create a method for each combination that exists which is really inconvenient. Is there something that can achieve this without having to make so many methods?
for example:
dollar to pound,
pound to yuan,
yuan to dollar,
euro to pound,
euro to dollar,
euro to yuan,
and more.
Each combination are not using the same formula.

Here is a code which might be more understandable

```
public int convert(String from, String to, int value){
return value * 1.33; //convert Canadian Dollar to US Dollar
}
```

But it only works with Canadian Dollar to US Dollar and not for other conversions

Comment: What combinations do you mean? Can you share some examples?

Comment: i could have £ to $, pound to yuan, dollar to bitcoin etc.

Comment: Maybe something like "convert(from, to)" would do the trick? One method, two parameters, source currency, target currentcy.

Comment: just one method, use two additional parameters to determine the currencies

Comment: My program will consist of many currencies you can convert to.

Comment: Do you know what im trying to say?

Comment: @user Separate methods for each combination indeed makes it difficult to extend, and clumsy to use. As others already have mentioned, `convert(from, to)` is probably a good option.

Comment: if I use one method, I would need a huge switch statement. Does that make sense?

Comment: maybe use a `Map` instead of a `switch` (and I believe I know what you are trying to say!)

Comment: @user : If you want your single method to work for many currencies, you will have to add the currency as parameter. You did not say how you model currencies in your application.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to overload the method. You can take the input and output currencies as parameters. E.g.:

```
public static double convert(double amount, String from, String to)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just  need to convert currencies you can take a currency as reference, then create a single method with source and target currencies as input, calculate exchange rate of each one based on reference currency. You may use a dictionary to store exchange rates against reference currency.